# CUDA: Calling a __device__ function from a kernel

Tags: cuda

I have a kernel that calls a **device** function inside an if statement. The code is as follows:

```
__device__ void SetValues(int *ptr,int id)
{
    if(ptr[threadIdx.x]==id) //question related to here
          ptr[threadIdx.x]++;
}

__global__ void Kernel(int *ptr)
{
    if(threadIdx.x<2)
         SetValues(ptr,threadIdx.x);
}
```

In the kernel threads 0-1 call SetValues concurrently. What happens after that? I mean there are now 2 concurrent calls to SetValues. Does every function call execute serially? So they behave like 2 kernel function calls?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

CUDA actually inlines all functions by default (although Fermi and newer architectures do also support a proper ABI with function pointers and real function calls). So your example code gets compiled to something like this

```
__global__ void Kernel(int *ptr)
{
    if(threadIdx.x<2)
        if(ptr[threadIdx.x]==threadIdx.x)
            ptr[threadIdx.x]++;
}
```

Execution happens in parallel, just like normal code. If you engineer a memory race into a function, there is no serialization mechanism that can save you.

Comment: i have a fermi card. does this mean that the function is Non-inlined? therefore the threadIdx.x in SetValues are all the threads and not just threads 0 and 1?

Comment: Functions are still inlined by default in Fermi. I think I understand what you are actually asking about now - which is what the scope of built-in per thread variables (like threadIdx) is inside __device__ functions. Am I getting warmer?

Comment: yes that is my question. but since __device__ functions are inline.. then i guess the scope of threads is the same as called using <<<blocks,threads>>> but because of the branch only threads 0 and 1 execute ptr[threadIdx.x]++. is this correct?